# php merge to same array if the key is array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi array like below and need to merge if a key (others) is an array. I tried with array_merge ( call_user_func_array('array_merge', $myArr) ) and its not working as expected.

```
Array
(
    [12] => Australia
    [36] => Canada
    [82] => Germany
    [97] => Hong Kong
    [100] => India
    [154] => New Zealand
    [190] => Singapore
    [222] => United Arab Emirates
    [223] => United Kingdom
    [224] => United States of America
    [Others] => Array
        (
            [1] => Afghanistan
            [3] => Algeria
            [4] => Andorra
            [6] => Anguilla
         )
)
```

How can i convert is to like below with out loosing the keys.

```
Array
(
    [12] => Australia
    [36] => Canada
    [82] => Germany
    [97] => Hong Kong
    [100] => India
    [154] => New Zealand
    [190] => Singapore
    [222] => United Arab Emirates
    [223] => United Kingdom
    [224] => United States of America
    [1] => Afghanistan
    [3] => Algeria
    [4] => Andorra
    [6] => Anguilla
)
```

**Update**
I can do it like this but i'm not sure that's the way to do it.

```
$temp = $myArr['others'];
unset($myArr['others']);
array_replace($myArr , $temp);
```

Comment: Show us your best attempt and let's see where exactly you failed.

Comment: Is it always called `"others"` or can there be other inner arrays?

Comment: Yes, it always be the same array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iterators to flatten the array:

```
$myArr = iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveArrayIterator($myArr)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just doing something like this:

```
if (array_key_exists('Others', $countries)) {
    foreach ($countries['Others'] as $index => $otherCountry) {
        if (array_key_exists($index, $countries)) {
            // handle collisions
        } else {
            $countries[$index] = $otherCountry;
        }
    }
}
```

Although this is bad practice, here is a one liner that can flatten your array:

```
$allCountries = iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($countries)));
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm looking for a one liner code, please see my update above.

Comment: Can I ask you why you have this requirement? Hiding complexity is usually not recommended

Comment: I edited my answer to add a one liner that works. Still not recommended though :)

Answer (score 0):

I have made a custom function that might work for you. It can take care of as many nested arrays that are there.

```
<?php
$test = array(
    12 => 'Australia',
    36 => 'Canada',
    82 => 'Germany',
    97 => 'Hong Kong',
    100 => 'India',
    154 => 'New Zealand',
    190 => 'Singapore',
    222 => 'United Arab Emirates',
    223 => 'United Kingdom',
    224 => 'United States of America',
    'Others' => array(
        1 => 'Afghanistan',
        3 => 'Algeria',
        4 => 'Andorra',
        6 => 'Anguilla',
        "test" => array(10 => 'Hello', 11 => 'World')
    )
);

$new = array();
my_merge($new, $test);
var_dump($new);

function my_merge(&$result, $source)
{
    foreach ($source as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            my_merge($result, $value);
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```